# Oracle 11g: osutil package; no PATH on CentOS 7?

Tags: c, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to invoke external programs via PL/SQL in Oracle 11g. [This](https://www.akadia.com/services/libosint_code.txt) is the C code of the shared library and [this](https://www.akadia.com/services/libosint_plsql_package.txt) is the corresponding PL/SQL wrapper for it.

Let's suppose I want to execute Unix's `ps -A` command. Here's what I got:

```
Connected to Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 
Connected as sys@orcl AS SYSDBA

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec osutil.RunOsCmd('ps -A');

ERROR, bad command or no output returned...
ERROR, bad command or no output returned...

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

What I find odd about it is that, should I `exec osutil.RunOsCmd('echo This works, but ps does not?!?');` instead, it gives me the command's output, like it should:

```
This works, but ps does not?!?

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Let's try echoing $ORACLE_HOME...

```
SQL> exec osutil.RunOsCmd('echo $ORACLE_HOME');

/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Now let's try echoing $PATH...

```
SQL> exec osutil.RunOsCmd('echo $PATH');



PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

It would seem to me that the library's `popen` command, when executed via Oracle's `extproc`, invokes an `sh` shell without anything in its $PATH.

Any idea why this is happening? I'd like to execute `ps -A` from Oracle without specifying the full path to the command, i.e. `/bin/ps -A`.

Comment: Run `exec osutil.RunOsCmd('/usr/bin/env')` to see the environment the shell inherits from the Oracle process.  It is quite possible that Oracle unsets the `PATH` environment variable for some inane reason; it is Oracle after all.  BTW, your links are swapped, the first one points to the wrapper.

Comment: `exec osutil.RunOsCmd('/usr/bin/env')` also yields an empty `PATH` variable, as seen [here](https://pastebin.com/s9idM8wJ)

Comment: `echo` is a shell builtin, that's why it works. Try in a bash the following two command lines `PATH= /bin/bash -c "echo TEST"` and `PATH= /bin/bash -c "ps -A"`. @NominalAnimal the "inane" reason is probably called "security", i.e. not falling into traps when somebody can manipulate your `$PATH`

Comment: @StefanBecker: That "somebody" is the user the oracle server runs as. Which is already trusted. That "security" is equivalent to removing tires from a bicycle, to avoid puncturing them.

Comment: @MiguelMartins: I recommend you modify the wrapper to preprend a configurable `export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin ;` to the string executed.

Comment: @StefanBecker the two command lines yield as follows:
`TEST`
and
`/bin/bash: ps: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by adding the following line to my `extproc.ora` file, which, in my case, is located under `/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/hs/admin`:

```
SET PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

It would seem Oracle 11g's `extproc` does indeed unset the `PATH` environment variable; in fact, it seems `extproc` has its own environment, which is only configurable through the `extproc.ora` file mentioned above.